# How do i resolve default iOS elements to a particular trait?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uitraitcollection, ios-darkmode

How do i resolve a default iOS system element, like say `UISegmentedControl`, to a particular interface style?

I know colors can be resolved like this.

```
color.resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))
```

How do i do the same for default iOS elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the system interface style by using `UIView` property `overrideUserInterfaceStyle`. Use this property to force the view to always adopt a light or dark interface style.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    segmentedControl.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
}
```

For more details see docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/3238086-overrideuserinterfacestyle).

Relevant WWDC video - [Implementing Dark Mode on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/). (27:00)

Comment: Ahhh... shucks. This should have struck me. I remember seeing this on their video where they talk about how you can set styles for windows, views, etc. Thanks mate.